# Python not committing MySQL transaction

Tags: python, mysql

I am inserting a couple thousand records into a table via the python code below:

```
values = ''
for row in cursor:
    values = values + "(" + self.quoted_comma_separate(row) + "),"
values = values[:-1]
insert_statement = "INSERT INTO t1 ({0}) VALUES {1};".format(
self.comma_separate(members), values)
db = Database()
conn = db.get_db()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(insert_statement)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

When I check the database after it runs none of the records show up in the database. If I go into an MySQL editor and manually commit the transaction all of the records appear. Why is my conn.commit() not working?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like spitting out the sql you're generating?

Comment: @MarcB Don't be silly, that's what SO is for.

Comment: First try printing your `insert_statement` to ensure it looks like valid SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert statements were fine. Turns out I had another database connection open and it was getting confused and committing to the wrong connection or something like that. Sorry for the pointless question :)